# Converting .adp to .accdb in Access 2010. How do I handle the SQL functions and stored procedures?

Tags: function, ms-access-2010, scalar

I am converting a `.adp` to `.accdb` in MS Access 2010 and I have the Forms, Reports, Macros and Modules imported into the new (`.accdb`) from the original (`.adp`) and I have linked to SQL tables and views.

Now I need to handle the stored procedures and functions, and searching the user forums hasn't helped me explicitly enough.  VBA is brand new to me, although my SQL is strong and my Access experience is modest, but existent.

For example, here is a scalar function in SQL that won't run as a query in the `.accdb` (although it works just fine in the `.adp`):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [db_owner].[ivp]
    (
    @pmData NTEXT
    )
RETURNS BIT
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Out    BIT
        SET @Out = 1
        IF PATINDEX('%dead:Y%', @pmData) > 0 SET @Out = 0
        IF PATINDEX('%inactive:Y%', @pmData) > 0 SET @Out = 0
    RETURN @Out
    END
```

Any ideas?  Thanks, everyone!

Comment: With an Access [pass-through query](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Process-SQL-on-a-database-server-by-using-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42), you can submit a query using SQL Server syntax, stored procedures, user-defined functions, etc. to the server.  One caveat is that for a query which returns a recordset, it will be read-only in Access.  That may not give you everything you need, but still could be a good start.

Comment: I will check out the pass-through query option, thank you!

Comment: I've gotten a pass-through query to run successfully, but what if I want it to accept a variable value and return data based on that value?

Comment: There are several ways, but they are not as convenient as you probably wish.  You could alter the `.SQL` property of a saved pass-through `QueryDef` to include your parameter values.  You could create a temporary `QueryDef` and add its `.Connect` and `.SQL` properties.  Or you could use an `ADO.Connection` to your SQL Server db and use its `.Execute` method to run your query.

Comment: I am going to look into the ADO.Connection method as some of the pass-through queries are pretty lengthy (several INNER and OUTER JOINs to nested SELECT clauses, etc) and coding them in VBA sounds like a nightmare.